# Why does our Netgear FS105 Port Splitter no longer work at our new apartment?

Tags: networking, internet-connection, switch

I have a Netgear FS105 5-way port splitter for splitting an internet connection from a router. At our previous apartment, the combination of a router hooked to our Time Warner Cable Coaxial internet connection, connected by an ethernet port to this splitter, with two ethernet cords extending to our laptop and desktop, worked perfectly for providing our two systems with an internet connection.

At our new apartment, this no longer seems to work. With the same setup, we can only get one computer at a time to receive any connection. Both computers seem to recognize the presence of a connection, but while one connects successfully, the other reports an "Unidentified Network".

IPConfig /retry does not work. We get the following error message on our network connections:

Ethernet does not have a valid IP-Config for wired connected.

We have also tried using a hotspot connection from my desktop, but this did not work either.

This is the splitter we are trying to use: http://support.netgear.com/product/FS105

Comment: are your computers set for DHCP?

Comment: @Keltari I'm not sure. How would I find out?

Comment: Either your old router did NAT or your old ISP gave you more than one IP address. Both which would explain why the Ethernet switch didn't work as expected. What modem is the Ethernet switch connected to?

Comment: Start by using the correct terminology. That's not a port splitter, it's a network switch. A "port splitter" and a switch are decidedly very different things.

Comment: When you say, "we can only get one computer at a time", that sounds like you have the switch connected to the modem, and not to the router.

Comment: what kind of "router" is it? full make and model number please.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, it looks like your switch (not a port splitter) is directly connected to a modem. At your old place, it was probably a modem/router combined unit. All you need to do is go to BestBuy or wherever and  ask for an ethernet router. They'll know exactly what you mean (you can also get an ethernet router + wifi for your devices, ask the guy at the store). It will have multiple ports on the back so you won't need your existing Netgear switch anymore.

Best of luck!

Comment: That's probably the issue.  THe thing though is that we didn't have any additional boxes at the old place - everything we had we brought with us.  Cables, boxes, everything.  The only difference was location, and the fact that I needed to use the longer cable for my PC since it was further away (where we'd previously used it for the further-away laptop).